# how to append open ports to an already functional iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables, salt

I'm running what's getting to be a large implementation of salt. I've been using lokkit commands to open ports for my servers, which works for the short term, but I'm running into some scary limitations. The main being that I can't figure out if it's possible to append open ports to ports that are already open in iptables. As far as I can tell, you have to open all of the ports you want with a single command. If you run the command afterwards and you don't include a port you had opened already, it will be closed after the command. I have two questions. The first, is it possible to simply append an open port using lokkit? I couldn't find the option in the docs. The second would be, if that isn't possible, could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The answer I have come up with is specific to Salt, but it works. The answer is not to use lokkit and use salt's native iptables state.

https://salt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.iptables.html

Simply use this state to append the additional ports you want opened.